# Notation for ∆y used in Necessary Second Order Condition Proof

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

**Edit:** I have updated the link so that it works!

I was watching a lecture for a  proof that if $x^*$ is a local maximiser of $f$ then necessarily the hessian is negative semi definite.

However i've got stuck on this notation: [Time stamped Source](https://youtu.be/ArqDkIQLqEw?t=329)

$∆y = f(λ∆x) = f(x^* + λ∆x) - f(x^*)$

- The $x's$ are vectors:
- He mentions later that "Dividing by $λ^2$  is basically dividing through by the square of the length of the vector $∆x$," which i guess implies that $∆x$ is very small and hence deriving most of it's length from λ?

1. I'm more used to defining a $∆x = x^* - x$ and $∆y = f(x^*) - f(x)$
2. I suppose given $y = f(x)$ we could take $y$ as $∆y$ and $x$ as $∆x$ hence we'd have $f(∆x)$ and then really $λ∆x = ∆x$ for some arbitrary change?
3. Then setting setting this = $f(x^* + λ∆x) - f(x^*)$ is equivalent to something like $f(x^* + hx) - f(x^*)$

But for example if you actually sub in $∆x = x^* - x$ you get something that looks like the convex combination of $x^*$ and $x$, so I'm really not convinced i know whats going on.

If anyone could walk me through this notation that would be great...

**Additional Context**

For context he then goes onto use the second degree Taylor polynomial:
$\nabla fλ∆x^* + \frac{1}{2}λ∆xH(x^*)λ∆x  + R_2(λ∆x)$
Where the final term is just his notation for the remainder term for the second degree Taylor series with respect to our augment, and then divides by $λ^2$ as mentioned, to reduce the remainder to 0.

Comment: I've also noticed in this video he writes $∆y = ∆f(∆x) = f(x) -  f(x^*)$. In general I've found this lecturer to be very good, and usually he even responds to comments, so I'm nervous to call the discrepancy a typo...but I don't really understand what's going on here: https://youtu.be/KesZslq5uVg?t=1158

Comment: AS for $f(\Delta y)$, I saw a very short part of the video of this lesson at minute 19: , it is strange, you are right, one had to see the video from the beginning, but there is something unusual. Coluld be a typo.

Comment: Hi BakerStreet, your comment reads as if thee was another part to it before the As?...Perhaps you were referencing the Brocken link in the video which I have now fixed!

Comment: Yes, the minute 19 of the video, where the professor writes $\Delta f( \Delta x)$

Comment: Ah okay that link in the comments works, you'll notice there is a different link which was Brocken (but now works) in the video which links to the notation I was trying to understand in the question! Subtly different to the notation in the comment...Look forward to your response whenever you get the time!

Comment: The link didn't work, actually. In the video , in my opinion, that is a typo, $f(\Delta x)$ makes no sense, as far as I saw.

Comment: Does the link for the first video work in the original post? It should take you to 5:30 in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArqDkIQLqEw&t=329s. He used $f(∆x)$ consistently here, but never $∆f(∆x)$ which definitely feels like a typo with the additional ∆ in front of the $f$

Comment: Yes, it works now.

Comment: Awesome! Also if you don't mind me asking what time zone is it for you now? You seem to be solving questions at all hours!

Comment: It is 3:35 p.m.

Comment: Ah cool you’re in Europe! I’m normally based in London, Peru atm. I’ve also made great progress with this, will post an answer soon. But there are still some grey areas

Comment: Ah you're in London, beautiful! I'll read what you will write as soon as possible!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142907/discussion-between-cormjack-and-bakerstreet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the following terms where $x$ and $y$ are vectors:

$∆x = x - x^*$

$\therefore x = ∆x + x^*$

$∆y = ∆f(x) = f(x) - f(x^*) = f(x^* + ∆x) - f(x^*)$

We can draw a fresh axis in terms of $∆x$ and $∆y$ essentially treating $x^*$ and $f(x^*)$ as the origin. This makes sense as $∆x$ and $∆f(x)$ evaluated at $x^* = 0$. We then call this function $F(∆x)$ (See attached diagram)

This gives the required: $∆y = F(∆x) = f(x) - f(x^*) = f(x^* + ∆x) - f(x^*)$

The  $∆x$ and $∆y$  axis imposed on the original graph can be seen at this point in the [video](https://youtu.be/KesZslq5uVg?t=882), the use of $F$ instead of $f$ can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/iPuMrI8wAl4?t=713).

**Answering Questions**

1. I believe that $∆F(∆x)$ seen [here](https://youtu.be/KesZslq5uVg?t=1165) was a typo and this should have either been $∆f(x)$ or $F(∆x)$
2. **What's the benefit of $F(∆x)$?** I'm not entirely sure, but I believe the author does this to allow him to talk about Limits as $(∆x) \to 0$
3. What's going on with  $∆y = F(λ{∆x}) = f(x^* + λ{∆x}) - f(x^*)$? Here he notes we are using a "fixed" $∆x$ and then taking λ scalar multiples of it. I suppose this is still just some arbitrary change representing $∆y$.
4. He uses λ so that he can then divide through by $λ^2$ which he says is the approximate length squared of the vector $(∆x)$ so that we get: $\frac{1}{λ^2}[\nabla f(x^*)•λ(∆x) + \frac{1}{2}λ(∆x)^TH(x^*)λ(∆x)  + R_2(λ{∆x})] = \frac{1}{2}(∆x)^TH(x^*)(∆x)$

- I have some questions about how we remove the remainder term $\lim \limits_{λ \to 0} \frac{R_2(λ∆x)}{(λ)^2} = 0$ , but I have added these in a [new post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/54457/remainder-term-in-linear-approximations-going-to-0)!
- Any other thoughts about the notation in general and the use of $F(λ{∆x})$ are welcome.

**$∆x$ and $∆y$ axis**
[image]

**Clearer explanation of the links:**

1. The [First Link](https://youtu.be/KesZslq5uVg?t=882) is showing an example of the axis using $∆x$ and $∆y$.
2. The [Second Link](https://youtu.be/iPuMrI8wAl4?t=713) if you look at the top line (LHS) of his notation we see the use of $F(∆x)$ which is different to $∆f(∆x)$ which is shown in the next link. These two notation are implied to mean the same thing and is a source of confusion discussed here.
3. The [Third Link](https://youtu.be/KesZslq5uVg?t=1165) shows the use of $∆f(∆x)$ notation.

- Here is an [additional example](https://youtu.be/E_wkLs1uv2E?t=1177) of $(∆x), (∆y)$ axis, when he first uses it. However it's more clear what's happening in the first link (because he gives arrows to the new axis there).

Comment: I find it , $ F(\Delta x)$, a quite strange notation, but it isn't possible to say anything more precise without seeing the video entirely. We have usaually the Taylor's formula with $x*=0$, that is called the formula of MacLaurin,  but there isn't  $ F(\Delta x)$, nor a translation af axes, even if could be the same. Maybe the professor here wants you to have a geometric insight, but it is impossible to say it without seeing the video. By the way, the video you linked in the other question maybe is wrong, it isn't the video to which the question refers to.

Comment: Hello there! Yes it is unusual I agree, the $F(∆x)$ makes some sense to me now, and I suppose he wanted to write things as a function of $∆x$. That being said I am confused still on $F(∆x)$ vs $∆f(∆x)$...I have made the video links explicit at the end, so that you understand the purpose of them and what to look for in the video. He's a very very good professor, like your explanations usually his are excellent...so perhaps if you do find the time you will get something from it! I'm not too worried now, but the explicit guide to the links at the bottom should help if you're curious! Many thanks!

Comment: I will try to listen to the video, I hope it colud be enough , because when there is a particular notation it is explained at the beginning of the lessons.  I've never seen in my books such a notation when explaining maximum conditions.